# How to keep my background image settings?

Tags: modeling, 3d-view, image

is there a method to store the settings of background images? I use them often as modeling reference in the viewport, but everytime I open up the blend-file all settings are gone:

[image: Settings during work]
*Settings during work*

[image]
*Settings after restart*

As long as you get the modeling done without a restart or changing the files, there is no problem. However it's annoying to replace all images over and over again.

Any ideas?

Comment: Blender does store the user interface when you save the file, just make sure that on the user settings>file you use **LoadUI** so that when you re-open your file those settings are loaded.

Comment: Go to File -- External Data -- Pack all into. blend and save

Comment: @atek That is unnecessary. Blender saves a link to the image when the file is saved. If that isn't working then packing won't help.